# Routing behaviour with Jquery AJAX call, MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

Hi Im trying to work out how to make Jquery ajax calls but I don't understand why my routing isn't going as expected.

My Routing is pretty standard

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Heres the controller action Im calling

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestPost(string teststring)
    {
        return Json("test");
    }
```

Here's my Ajax call

```
    $(document).ready(function (){
    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#input").submit(function (event) {

        /* stop form from submitting normally */
        event.preventDefault();

        alert('in the ajax');
        teststring = 'tested string';

        // check form is valid
        if ($("#input").valid()) {
            //ajax call!
            $.ajax({
                url : "Home/TestPost",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false
            });
        }
        else { return false }
```

But when I run this call it doesn't appear to be routing to Home/Testpost in the output window it appears to be heading for Home/Home/TestPost

```
    {"ver":2,"id":"ZjW6WxGC8Yg=","name":"POST Home/Home","duration":"00:00:00.0290000","success":false,"responseCode":"404","url":"http://localhost:20064/Home/Home/TestPost"
```

So I decided to remove the Home from my url so I don't get 2 of it but then I still get odd results, Testpost/Index

```
    ver":2,"id":"cfAk091y/V8=","name":"POST TestPost/Index","duration":"00:00:00.0100000","success":false,"responseCode":"404","url":"http://localhost:20064/TestPost","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
```

Confused at this behaviour

Comment: Always use `@Url.Action(...)` to generate your urls (which would have correctly generated `/Home/TestPost`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing one slash in AJAX call. you must have slash in front of

> Home

Controller in url value.

so your code must be like this :

```
   $.ajax({
                url : "/Home/TestPost",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false
            });
```